# Why would I put an ID on a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that some web developers put IDs on scripts tags.  For example:

```
<script id="scripty" src="something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know that according the W3C this is perfectly legal markup, but what's the benefits of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The one use I've seen of this is if you want to provide widget for customers and you instruct them to place the `<script>` tag wherever they want the widget to show up. If you give the `<script>` element an ID then you can reference that inside of it to place the code in the right place. That's not to say that it is the *only* way of achieving that, of course, but I've seen it done and [suggested it in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758676/how-can-i-append-a-new-element-in-place-in-javascript).

Answer (score 6):

I've seen it used for Microtemplating, where you can put a template in a script tag and then reference it through the ID.

[Here's great post with javascript microtemplating by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) - note that this is not the ONLY way of achieving this, only Johns version of it.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit is that you can refer to the element with an `id="foo"` using the global variable `window.foo` or just `foo`:

[image: id as a global variable]

Answer (score 1):

By using an ID, you can wait on the specific JS file to finish loading. FB does this

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

`facebook-jssdk` being their unique identifier.

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/8578840][1]