# Inject a script tag with remote src and wait for it to execute

Tags: javascript

How can I inject a `<script src="https://remote.com/"></script>` element into my page, wait for it to execute, and then use functions that it defines?

FYI: In my case, the script will do some credit card processing in rare cases, so I don't want to include it always.  I want to include it quickly when the user opens up a change-credit-card-options dialog, and then send it the new credit card options.

Edit for additional detail: I do not have access to the remote script.

Comment: Do you have control over the remote script? If so it might be easier to have the script itself call your code when it is done, a-la JSONP

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the remote script. Editing question to reflect that~

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You could use **Google Analytics** or **Facebook**'s method:

```
(function(d, script) {
    script = d.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    script.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Below is the new Facebook method; it relies on an existing script tag instead of `<head>`:

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

- Replace `facebook-jssdk` with your unique script identifier to avoid it being appended more than once.
- Replace the script's url with your own.

Comment: This seems perfect, but there is some chatter on the internet that onload isn't called by all browsers.  Do you know what browsers this would work with?

Comment: Why do you not append this to the body?

Comment: Instead of using `script.onload` or `js.onload`, I would add an event listener to the `load` event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564029/adding-to-window-onload-event

Comment: Is there a benefit to appending to another `script` vs appending it to the `head`? The downside I see to appending to `script`s is if there aren't any to append to it'd break.

Comment: In my case, I needed this for use as a **bookmarklet**, in which case this bookmarklet generator service was useful: http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ (just make sure you remove any comments from the code, as it does not filter those out by itself)

Comment: Note that the first query `d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]` can be moved below the `if` check to save yourself a DOM query if the script already exists.

Comment: How can it rely on the existing script tag in dom? injection of `facebook-jssdk` will raise an error if the user doesn't have any script tag in dom.

Comment: could not see any reason for using the load event in the attached question, can you please clarify ?
@ha404

Answer (score 59):

Same method using event listeners and ES2015 constructs:

```
function injectScript(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;
        script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
        script.addEventListener('error', e => reject(e.error));
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
}

injectScript('https://example.com/script.js')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Script loaded!');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Nice! This would make a good NPM package or ES6 module. 
+1 for having an example usage.

Comment: Have you have any idea why in then() body I cannot use variables/functions defined in the loaded script?

Comment: @dar0x Did you check the dev console? It's possible that it could get blocked by the site's Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 16):

This is one way to dynamically load and execute a list of scripts synchronously. You need to insert each script tag into the DOM, explicitly setting its async attribute to false:

```
script.async = false;
```

Scripts that have been injected into the DOM are executed asynchronously by default, so you have to set the async attribute to false manually to work around this.

## Example

```
<script>
(function() {
  var scriptNames = [
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js",
    "example.js"
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < scriptNames.length; i++) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scriptNames[i];
    script.async = false; // This is required for synchronous execution
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
  // jquery.min.js and example.js will be run in order and synchronously
})();
</script>

<!-- Gotcha: these two script tags may still be run before `jquery.min.js`
     and `example.js` -->
<script src="example2.js"></script>
<script>/* ... */<script>
```

## References

- There is a great article by Jake Archibald of Google about this called [Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/).
- The [WHATWG spec on the  tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script) is a good and thorough description of how  tags are loaded.

Comment: It is working now, upvoted. BTW, the last closing script is missing the backslash.

Answer (score 9):

## Dynamic `import()`

Using dynamic import, you can now load modules and wait for them to excute, as simply as this:

```
import("http://example.com/module.js").then(function(module) {
  alert("module ready");
});
```

If the module has already been loaded and executed, it won't get loaded and executed again, but the promise returned by `import` will still resolve.

Note that the file is loaded as a module, not as just a script. Modules are executed in strict mode, and they are loaded in module scope, which means variables are not automatically made global the way they are in normally loaded scripts. Use the `export` keyword in a module to share a variable with other modules or scripts.

## References:

- [Browser support for dynamic `import`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import)
- [ES modules: A cartoon deep-dive](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)
- [Dynamic `import()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import)

Answer (score 6):

something like this should do the trick:

```
(function() {
    // Create a new script node
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = function() {
        // Cleanup onload handler
        script.onload = null;

        // do stuff with the loaded script!

    }

    // Add the script to the DOM
    (document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ]).appendChild( script );

    // Set the `src` to begin transport
    script.src = "https://remote.com/";
})();
```

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: Is there a reason you manually set the script onload to null in the callback? Is there a problem with it triggering more than once, or is this just forcing some sort of garbage collection?

Comment: Yep, that is to avoid memory leaks in old IE, due to the script element referencing a function as the onload handler.

Answer (score 2):

**Create a loader**

You can inject the script in an **orderly manner** in a loader.

Beware that the execution of the dynamically loaded scripts usually comes after statically loaded scripts (i.e.`<script src="My_script.js"></script>`) (the order of injection in the DOM does not guarantee the opposite):

e.g., loader.js:

```
function appendScript(url){
   let script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = url;
   script.async = false //IMPORTANT
   /*Node Insertion Point*/.appendChild(script);
}
appendScript("my_script1.js");
appendScript("my_script2.js");
```

`my_script1.js` will effectively be executed before `my_script2.js`, (helpful if dependencies of `my_script2.js` are in `my_script1.js`)

Note it's important to have `script.async = false` because dynamically loaded scripts has `async = true` by default, `async` does not assure you the order of loading.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my adapted version, based on the answer of Frank with an additional expression to evaluate:

```
static async importScript(src, expressionToEvaluateAndReturn){

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.async = true;
            script.src = src;
            script.addEventListener('load', (event)=>{
                if(expressionToEvaluateAndReturn){
                    try{
                        let result = eval(expressionToEvaluateAndReturn);
                        resolve(result);
                    } catch(error){
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
            script.addEventListener('error', () => reject('Error loading script "' + src + '"'));
            script.addEventListener('abort', () => reject('Script loading aborted for "' + src + '"'));
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });    
        
    }
```

Example usage:

```
let d3 = await importScript('/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js','d3')
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        throw error;
                    });
```

Comment: Downvoted because you don’t explain what’s the difference with Frank’s answer.