# Rails 4: How to add external javascript file from other site in a specific page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I am using turbolink (rails4) and following js link gets generated by application.js file in my pages header section

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/global.js?body=1"></script>
```

My application.js looks something like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require respond.min.js
```

I want to add an external javascript file from OTHER site e.g. http://otherdomain.com/xyz.js in a specifc page of my site. Suppose I want to add this external js file ONLY in a specifc page http://mysite.com/profile And I want to add this js file ONLY in header part of the page. So how can I do that? Please don't suggest to save that external file locally as that is not an option for me.

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be in the header?

Comment: @Matt Yes it absolutely need to be in header

Answer (score 12):

Add a content block in your layout:

**layout.html.erb**:

```
...
<head>
  <%= yield(:header) %>
</head>
...
```

In the one template that requires the JS file, render it into that block:

**profile.html.erb**:

```
<% content_for(:header) do %>
  <script src="http://otherdomain.com/xyz.js"></script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this `<% if content_for?(:header) %>` part actually needed?  In this instance, yielding `:header` if there is no content will yield an output of nothing, effectively leaving a blank line just like this code does.  Seems like just going with `<%= yield(:header) %>` is the way to go.

Comment: My answer is from 2 years ago, so I can't remember why I added the conditional. I agree though, it's unnecessary. I'll update the answer. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

As cool as turbolinks are, I find myself with more headaches than before they existed.  I also inject page specific css or js in certain special circumstances it exists in the header.  It might be hacky, but I put it in the layout with a condition using the current_page? helper

```
 = javascript_include_tag "whatever.com/external.js" if ( current_page?(:controller => "users" ) && current_page?(:action => "index" ) )
```

Comment: trh, I have thought about that, but that is last hacky option and I will do that once there is no better option. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

A solution I'm looking at presently is [injecting the script dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578617/inject-a-script-tag-with-remote-src-and-wait-for-it-to-execute):

> ```
> (function(d, script) {
>     script = d.createElement('script');
>     script.type = 'text/javascript';
>     script.async = true;
>     script.onload = function(){
>         // remote script has loaded
>     };
>     script.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
> }(document));
> ```