# How to add javascript to JBrowse after everything has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous, jbrowse

I'm trying to add a script tag to the body of index.html in JBrowse 11.5.
I want it to be executed after everything has loaded. All the CSS, asynchronously loaded tracks and so on.
I've tried domReady! and dom/ready but they are triggered too early.
Does anyone know how to add a script after all has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on what you mean by "everything being loaded", but you could try a couple different methods.

For example, in index.html you might write something like this

```
JBrowse.afterMilestone('initView', function() {
    // add your code to inject script here
})
```

You can just add arbitrary javascript there, include new AMD modules, or use some other code injection type method e.g. [inject a script tag with remote src and wait for it to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578617/inject-a-script-tag-with-remote-src-and-wait-for-it-to-execute)

Alternatively, check out the plugin architecture for JBrowse, it is also a good way to include new code modules