# Executing a <script> tag on append after the DOM has loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, append

I'm trying to watch videos onClick in a modal without having to visit the video pages themselves.

I'm using Vue.js and through a series of Ajax calls I am able to get most of the way there.

Codpen: https://codepen.io/nolaandy/pen/BrbBzO

If you click "vs Suns" at top, you get a listing of all video posts. Then clicking any of the images, the modal component pops up and takes in the title of the post dynamically.

I want to run a video in there as well so I try to run this script tag:

```
 < script class="_nbaVideoPlayerScout" data-team="warriors" data-videoId="/video/{{unique videoId from post ajax call}}" data-width="768" data-height="732" src="https://www.nba.com/scout/team/cvp/videoPlayerScout.js"></script>
```

When the modal pops up, I see the correct title of the post/image I clicked on, and I see the script tag exactly as it should be in the inspector, but the script tag never runs.

Is there some different way I should be injecting this script than this? (This is inside the axios response call)

```
let theVideoId = response.data.content[0].videoID


let s = document.createElement('script')
s.setAttribute('class', '_nbaVideoPlayerScout')
s.setAttribute('data-team', 'warriors') 
s.setAttribute('data-videoId', '/video/' + theVideoId) 
s.setAttribute('data-width', '768') 
s.setAttribute('data-height', '732') 
s.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.nba.com/scout/team/cvp/videoPlayerScout.js')
document.getElementById('popupVideo').appendChild(s);
```

MODAL COMPONENT -- Fired on the click of one of the post thumbnails

```
const videoModal = Vue.component('VideoModal', {
props: {
    id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    }
},
data: function () {
  return {
    post: [],
  }
},
mounted() {
  const singleApi = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.nba.com/warriors/api/1.1/json?textformat=html&nid='
  axios.get(singleApi + this.id).then((response) => {
    this.post = response.data.content[0]
    console.log('THE RESPONSE', response)

    let theVideoId = response.data.content[0].videoID


let s = document.createElement('script')
s.setAttribute('class', '_nbaVideoPlayerScout')
s.setAttribute('data-team', 'warriors') 
s.setAttribute('data-videoId', '/video/' + theVideoId) 
s.setAttribute('data-width', '768') 
s.setAttribute('data-height', '732') 
s.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.nba.com/scout/team/cvp/videoPlayerScout.js')
document.getElementById('popupVideo').appendChild(s);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

},
methods: {
  goBack: function () {
    router.go(-1)
  }
},
template:`<div>
<div id="video-popup">
  <button class="close-video-popup" @click="goBack">close me</button>
  <div class="video-popup-wrapper">
    <div class="video-popup--title">{{post.title}}</div>
    <div class="video-popup--video" id="popupVideo"></div>
  <div class="video-popup--share"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`
})
```

Comment: this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/8578840/1309377

Comment: I wish that worked but I get the same thing. Script added but nothing is run.

Comment: It's crazy because if I add a script with an alert in it, I get the alert popup:     var s = document.createElement('script')
    s.type = 'text/javascript'
    var code = 'alert("'+theVideoId+'");'
    
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.getElementById('scriptMe').appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.getElementById('scriptMe').appendChild(s);
    }

Comment: are there any errors in the dev console? What do you expect to happen when you load this script?

Comment: I'm trying to show a video. No errors at this time. If you add this script tag into a codepen you will see the video popup:  

<script class="_nbaVideoPlayerScout" data-team="warriors" data-videoId="/video/teams/warriors/2018/04/09/2041192/1523301309011-shorts-phx-2041192" data-width="768" data-height="732" src="https://www.nba.com/scout/team/cvp/videoPlayerScout.js">< / script>

I can inject this exact script but I don't get the video.

Comment: Here's a codepen. I have the video embed as is. I then have an external JS file with a simple Alert in it that fires correctly. Lastly I have the video embed script injected in a similar fashion to the external alert.   https://codepen.io/nolaandy/pen/WzmQKR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a whim I made this change:

```
// document.getElementById('scriptMe').appendChild(s);
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

and boom, script runs and video loads.

Which is super interesting, because "why", right?

Edit:
In addition, trying other script injection methods [discussed here](https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/).

#### document.write method

```
document.write(s.outerHTML) // s is a script node
```

also works. In fact, you can embed that script node in a `div` and it works as well.

#### createContextualFragment method

```
// var $container = document.getElementById('scriptMe'); // does not work
var $container = document.body
var range = document.createRange()
$container.appendChild(range.createContextualFragment(script_str))
```

works, where `script_str` is an html string literal. This will work both as `"<script>....</script>"` or `"<div id="myDiv"><script>...</script></div>"`

but all the methods I tested ultimately needed injection to be done in `body`.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/uncleoptimus/pen/vRPKrq?editors=1010)

Comment: Wow that's very annoying. You're amazing for figuring that out! Do you have any idea on how I would load this into a specified div?

Comment: There is, sort of. But it might not fit your criteria. First of all, [tip o the hat to this article](https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/). And here is [a forked pen with the working example](https://codepen.io/uncleoptimus/pen/vRPKrq?editors=1010). Uses `createContextualFragment` but *notice how the fragment must include the `div` container*! In all the methods I tried, I had to append to the `body` to get the script to run. Very interesting. The linked article has another method you can test as well.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It appears you're correct in only being able to append to the document.body. I was able to move the video with the below code (Setting a timeout for 3 seconds and using a fragment). I see many potential problems with this though, the first being what happens if it takes longer than 3 seconds for the video to load?

setTimeout(function(){
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById('container'));
  document.getElementById('scriptMe').appendChild(fragment);
}, 3000);

Comment: Yea I am in the dark as to *why* exactly this is the case but my suspicion is that it has something to do with the nba video player library. What I realized after a bit of testing was that the player script *does load and run*, no issue, as we expected! But when it does execute, some condition check or whatnot in the player script causes the `init()` function to not be run. So for now,, I will just blame it on them hahah