# how replace the id in src script with var in file config

Tags: javascript, analytics, var

```
<html>
    <head> 
       <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxx">         
       </script>
<html>
        replace value xxx by var get from config 
<script async  src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=Var">
```

I want to replace the value of the id in src of script with a variable that I get from conf file

any help?

Comment: once the page loaded, get the src of the whatever script you needed, manipulate it  and create a new script tag  with the id  you get after manipulation and append to head.try this

Comment: think this might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578617/inject-a-script-tag-with-remote-src-and-wait-for-it-to-execute

Comment: Add the script tag to your document `<head>` and give it an id, e.g.: `<script id="async_script" src=""></script>` and once that is done simply call the Specific tag with its **id** `const script = document.getElementById('async_script');`, then simply just replace it like this `script.src = script.src.replace('xxxx', number);`.

Answer (score 0):

As `HTML` is "read" by the web browser, you won't be able to simply add a variable to a `<script>` tag. You can accomplish this through pure Javascript by loading in the file dynamically as stated here: [Dynamically load JS inside JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Where `id_number` is the number you are attempting to add:

```
var url_string = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=' + id_number
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //do stuff with the script
};
script.src = url_string;

document.head.appendChild(script);
```