# How do I store the id number from getElementById in a variable and then use it in an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, esp8266

I am trying to cut some code from my `esp8266` script by using a function to change the `href` address in the browser when a button is clicked. I want the id number to be stored in the variable so that I can reuse it to set the pin number if that particular button id is clicked.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log("button was clicked");
  var x = document.getElementById(Element.id);
  console.log(x);

  document.getElementById(x).setAttribute("onClick",
      "javascript:window.location.href='/toggle?pin_number='" + x);
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="4" onClick="myFunction()">TOGGLE D4</button><br>
<button class="button" id="5" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='/toggle?pin_number=5'">TOGGLE D5</button><br>
<button class="button" id="6" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='/toggle?pin_number=6'">TOGGLE D6</button><br>
```

the `console.log(x)` returns `null`.

I don't know whether this is the best way to do it or not because I'm new to `javascript`.

Comment: Pass the element to your function, ie `onclick="myFunction(this)"`

Comment: I'd use `<a>`'s instead of `<button>`'s since they seem to be links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the element to your function.

```
<button class="button" id="4" onClick="myFunction(this)">TOGGLE D4</button>
```

Then, in the function, accept an argument (let's call it `e` in this case) which accepts the element.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  console.log("button was clicked");
  console.log(e);
}
```

Now, if you want to get at the elements `id` that was clicked, simply access the `id` property like:

```
console.log(e.id);
```

On another note, HTML5 isn't that strict anymore but [HTML4 used to have these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/215042) for an id:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[It's a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#comment2031832_79022) to [stick with these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/215042).

It's even better to use the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value) attribute:

```
<button class="button" value="4" onClick="myFunction(this)">TOGGLE D4</button>
```

And then use `e.value`:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  console.log("button was clicked:", e.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I got it now.

```
function myFunction(x) {
console.log(x.id);
window.location.href='/toggle?pin_number=' + x.id;
}
```

tested and working :)

Comment: It'd be nice if you accepted someone's answer; it's nice that you post your solution but what you posted was given to you in the answers.

Comment: @RobIII how do I accept an answer? I clicked on the up arrow next to your post to say it was useful. Im new here, there was no need to be rude about it. I said thanks.....

Comment: I don't see where I was rude? And if I was it sure wasn't intended to be. You can click the checkmark to accept an answer. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate code, here a short code to do  what you want:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(function(b) {//<-- iterates the buttons

  b.addEventListener("click", function(t) {//<-- adds event listener
  
    console.log(t.target.id)//<-- we get the data
    
  })
  
});
```

```html
<button class="button" id="4">TOGGLE D4</button><br>
<button class="button" id="5">TOGGLE D5</button><br>
<button class="button" id="6">TOGGLE D6</button><br>
```

We add an event listener to every button, then we get the id using `event.target.id`

Comment: Thanks, Emeeus. A little harder to understand but I think I got it. I will go do some more reading.

Comment: @JasonL I've added an extra explanation, by the way it would not be better if you use ajax? because the goal is to send this to the esp rigth?

Comment: this is running on the esp. Its just a basic webpage that i log into that has buttons to turn the pins on and off.

Comment: the goal was to pretty up the interface a little while keeping the code small and learning some new things. I've achieved all three today :D

Comment: @JasonL to save memory see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578617/inject-a-script-tag-with-remote-src-and-wait-for-it-to-execute you could store the code remotely, not in the esp