# Injecting actual brython code from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, brython

I have the code taken from [Inject a script tag with remote src and wait for it to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578617/inject-a-script-tag-with-remote-src-and-wait-for-it-to-execute):

```
function injectScript(src){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;
        console.log(script.src)
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
        script.addEventListener('error', e => reject(e.error));
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

By writing

```
injectScript((chrome.runtime.getURL("/utils.js")))
    .then(() => {
        console.log("script loaded")
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I can successfully inject my code from utils.js (below) into an html page which I have verified works with seperately injected html code with a button with `onclick="foo()"`

```
function foo(){
    console.log("bar");
}
```

Now, my question is how do I modify my injectScript function to inject my brython code (below)? I have tried setting the type attribute to `text/python` but otherwise keeping it the same, but this does not work. Similarly changing `script.src = src` to `script.textContent = src` does not work. In all cases, simply nothing happens without an error.

```
***python.js***

from browser import document, alert

def hello():
    alert("hello world")

document['mybutton'].bind('click', hello)
```

Edit:
Full code used for injecting brython code (console logs 'min script loaded' and 'stdlib script loaded' but not 'python loaded' nor alerts 'hello world':

```
 injectScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.9/brython.min.js")
    .then(() => {
        console.log('min script loaded!');
        injectScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.9.5/brython_stdlib.min.js")
            .then(() => {
                console.log('stdlib script loaded!');
                
                injectPython((chrome.runtime.getURL("/python.js")))
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("python loaded")
                    }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Browser can't run brython directly so you need to inject the interpreter first.

Comment: Do you mean injecting something other than brython.min.js and brython_stdlib.min.js (have injected both and call injectScript within their initial .then() clause, still no dice)? Talk to me as if i've never used brython before...

Comment: have editted the fuller script, thanks

Comment: I doubt they will run on a page with strict CSP. Try downloading these scripts (manually) into the extension directory and then inject them using chrome.runtime.getURL.

Comment: Still no luck. I still get console logs for min/stdlib script loaded but not 'python loaded'. No CSP warnings (didn't have that before loading the brython src urls either). Logging the python.js script src during injectScript function says chrome-extension://mcclncbnkdfngjnmjjenobbadjoaabnp/python.js which seems reasonable, but still, nothing happens