# testing a addEventListener using jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have this method in index.js

```
function init(config: CartConfig): void {

    let env = "";
    if (config.env==='prod'){
        env = "";
    }else if (config.env === 'staging'){
        env="stg.";
    }else{
        env="qa.";
    }

    const cart = document.createElement('script');
    cart.type = "module";
    cart.src = "https://www." + env + "delta.com/digital/cart-3/cart.js";

    cart.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

        const footer = document.querySelector("main~footer") as HTMLElement;
        if (footer) {
            insertCartElementBefore(footer);
            setupCartApiDidFinish(config);
            mountCart(config);
            setupNavigationButtons(config);
            hidePrimarySubmitButton(config);
            movePopupActionClassToEncapsulateSubmitButtons();
        }

    });
    document.head.appendChild(cart);

}
```

and I have a test in test file,  I am wondering why the cart.addEventListener("load") method instructions are not called and how can I call them

````
it(`check if the script is added to the head`, async () => {

            init();
            screen.debug();

          });
    ```
````

Comment: Seems like the fact you're injecting script and trying to test that is very relevant to the issue. Have you looked around about that? [Related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578617/7665043).