# What is the point of using an ID attribute in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Basically what I am asking is what is the point of giving my script tags an id attribute?  Can the routines inside of them be called or referenced differently because of this identification?  Could this cause any problems making the script/page act funny?

Comment: There isn't really any point to adding an id to a script tag. Is there a specific instance that you are asking about?

Comment: So what's the problem here? Sometimes it is useful to add an `id` to a `script` tag when you want to parse it.

Comment: Not necessarily a problem i had just recently come across some code in which all the script tags had id attribute I was curious as to why if they serve no purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would I put an ID on a script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219851/why-would-i-put-an-id-on-a-script-tag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would I put an ID on a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219851/why-would-i-put-an-id-on-a-script-tag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `id` is just another accessor of the `<script>` tag inside the DOM tree. You could in theory use `document.getElementById()` to retrieve the `<script>` node and delete it or add other attributes (though I don't believe you can modify the `src` attribute once it has loaded in the DOM).  The `id` isn't required for those operations though -- it could have been accessed by any DOM function such as `getElementsByTagName("script")` as well.

If you do need to access the `<script>` tag with DOM manipulations, the `id` makes it just a little easier. Otherwise, there is little benefit<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>That is sort of true of adding an `id` attribute to *any* DOM node, though nodes affecting presentation can also benefit from CSS targeting the `id`, unlike a `<script>` tag...

Comment: I want to manipulate my script id, is it possible? I mean i have <script id=123> into my index page which is manipulate different pages. If I add this script it appears in all pages. But i don't want in all pages only on specific one.

Answer (score 6):

As the earlier answers have mentioned, once the code in the script tag runs, it's results will not be undo-ed by replacing/deleting the script node.

But the id can be useful if the code has not run till now. Following is such a script tag:

```
<script id="code1" type="text/myjs">.....</script>
```

Since the browser is not aware of this type of script, it will ignore it's execution but the tag and it's code will still be available in the DOM.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sv_in/rt9Q2/

This is largely used for client side templates. A template, example for [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), is stored in such a script tag. When it is needed to be compiled, it is obtained from tag using it's id. Advantage with this approach is that the view (templates) and the model (js variable which contain data to be shown in the view) is completely separate.

Other than this practise, there is no general purpose use for an id for a script tag

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaning giving id to your script tags, the scripts on a page just execute in a sequence they are on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an id attribute to your script elements serves 2 specific purposes:
1. you can recognise your scripts when reading the web page's source code;
2. the HTML reference says you should be able to overwrite the contents of an identifiable element (but experience teaches us that few browsers actually do that).

For instance, if you already have a script with id="myParticularScript", then adding a new script element with that same id should replace the old one, loading any new (or the same) source you specified in the src attribute.

While my experience with dynamic loading of javascripts proves that the new script does get loaded into the browser, no browser I tested managed to replace the older element that holds the same id.

So that just leaves the first purpose: easy recognition. In my work, we use systems to generate web pages, and we didn't always know which script (or css link, for that matter) is added by which component. We solved this by adding ids to both the script tags and the css link tags - ids that we were able to recognise and trace back to our systems.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for checking the existence of the resource file in the src url attribute in the server. For cache busting, reverencing the file name of .js and .css files are required. This will help in checking out if the file names has changed in the server and then do a reload via code via

```
$window.location.reload()
```

Code example (angularjs):

```
service.reloadApplication = function () {
    var script = document.getElementsById("scriptAppMin");                  
    if (!!script.getAttribute('src') &&       doesFileExist(script.getAttribute('src')) == false)
                            $window.location.reload();                                                             
    }


 function doesFileExist(fileUrl) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', fileUrl, false);
    xhr.send();
    return !(xhr.status == "404");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one use nobody mentioned: the `id="test"` attribute sets the global variable `test` pointing to the element itself. See:

[image: id as a global variable]

Answer (score 0):

I found a very novel use for giving ID to a `script` tag. I had embedded [tawk.to](https://www.tawk.to/) script in my website to show its chat widget. The problem is, the widget does not hide when I want to print the page. So you would see the widget repeated on every page in the print preview, often obscuring the page contents!

In order to resolve the problem, I first observed how the widget is added. I found out that the widget is added right after the script tag. But the widget (encased in a `div` tag) does not have any class, and it has a randomly generated ID which is different each time.

There had to be another way to catch hold of that widget (the `div` tag) without relying on JavaScript tricks. That's when I learnt that CSS has an ["adjacent sibling"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or "next sibling" selector, which surprisingly has very decent browser support.

So first, **I gave an ID for the script tag**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="tawk-to-script">
```

Then I **used the ID** and the next sibling selector to apply CSS to the widget.

```
@media print {
  script#tawk-to-script + div {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Viola! Problem solved.

Comment: _Never underestimate the use of a seemingly useless feature. It could become a life-saver one day._ **PS:** Tawk.to support has washed their hands about fixing this, saying they can't control how the user's website chooses to print, but you and I know that's a load of bullshit. It's very easy for them to add a media query to hide the widget for print media.

Answer (score 0):

I used `script` `id` tag in a bookmarklet; I add the `script` element via Javascript to `DOM` alongwith a `div`; then use it; & when/if user clicks the `Close` button on my added `div`; I find this `script` element by ID & delete it from DOM to leave the page as I found it.

Answer (score 0):

They might come in handy when you think of loading scripts lazily. Also, I remember I once used an ID on a script tag to facilitate the changes on meta content, per state change (it was a single page application).

With an ID on a script tag, you can check if on a particular instance, whether a script tag with a particular ID is there in the DOM or not. If it's not there, and if your route requires it to be there, you can load it then (given on certain conditions).

Suppose there's a script that you need to load lazily. Let's take an example of some chat widget. Cases can arise that may tend you to load the chat widget only and only whenever a user happens to click on, say, a chat button.

Here, you'll be lazily loading the chat. So, a possible case out of it can be:
"if user clicks on chat button, inject the chat widget js into the DOM".

Simple? Hell yes. But, think about the case when a user clicks on the chat button again. What will happen? The same script would be injected again, but you certainly don't want that to happen, do you?

So, let's say the chat widget js goes into the DOM by:

```
<script id="chatWidgetScript" src="...whatever..."></script>
```

A good solution to tackle the "second click" problem on the chat button will be to see if the script already exists in the DOM, and if it does, don't let the same get appended twice into the DOM.

So, your button could be:

```
<button onclick="loadChatWidget()"> Chat! </button>
```

And your loadChatWidget() function could be:

```
loadChatWidget(){
     if(document.getElementById("chatWidgetScript")){
          //chat script is already there in the DOM, no need to load it again.
          return;
     }

     /* 
     if document.getElementById("chatWidgetScript") returns null, this would 
     mean that the chat widget isn't there in the DOM, and you might want to 
     load the same now.
     */

     // LOAD SCRIPT HERE
}
```

This is just one way of using an ID on a script tag, and it is useful too!