# Target script selector class by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to target the jQuery selector class and change it some for a purpose. My code is in php string like below.

```
<?php echo '<span class="demo"><script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $(".dt").iconpicker(); });</script></span>';?>
```

I know there is `attr` selector but it may work on `img` or `input` and other tags . How about the script tag ? Is it possible ? Please suggest me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you do this, however the answer is YES it is possible to pick the `script` tag using [Element Selecting](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), *with no id `#` nor class `.` prefixes*, just like `$('span.demo>script')` or `$('span.demo script')` sure you can omit the span word and write it like `$('.demo...)`.

As shown in this **[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/se0z-ymqb)** - *hit run or F9 to execute* - I was able to pick the script tag and alter its inner html (or text) - *check this script element with the dev tool inspecter* - but I couldn't execute the new injected function `myColor()` as you can see in this image:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<?php 
    echo '<span class="demo"><script>alert("My original span next");</script></span>';
?>
<script>
    var $html = "myColor();";
    $('span.demo>script').html($html);

    function myColor(){
        $('span.demo').css({'background-color':'#FBB','border-color':'red'});
    }
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you can give that `script` tag an `id` attribute and pick it directly, just like in this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/wqqqus63/) again check the `span.demo` with the dev tool inspector. check these two links for more information:

[What is the point of using an ID attribute in a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960180/what-is-the-point-of-using-an-id-attribute-in-a-script-tag)

[Giving the script tag an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741441/giving-the-script-tag-an-id)