# What is significance of bootstrap in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, bootstrapping

I need to know what is the importance of putting this statement

`id="sap-ui-bootstrap"` in the script tag.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/fe12df2e338e43598977d09f3d191b7b.html

If I don't put the above statement then also the application runs without any issue. So, just curious to know why by default eclipse put this statement.

Can someone just point some light to it?

~Rahul

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is used to identify the script tag in order to read the `data-sap-ui-*` attributes with are used for [configuration](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f08de06f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) of the bootstrap.

Comment: I was checking this link - [What is the point of using an ID attribute in script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960180/what-is-the-point-of-using-an-id-attribute-in-a-script-tag) and found that we can access script node in DOM. But configs mentioned in the script will be loaded only once so we cannot add or delete it.