# Insert a script tag before another specific script tag

Tags: javascript

I have these lines to call my JS files and libraries:

```
<script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/library.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Dynamically, I need to insert a new library. So I would make:

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Where script is my new library.

But how can I insert it just before `library.js` ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML before element in JavaScript without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315948/insert-html-before-element-in-javascript-without-jquery)

Comment: You could add an id to the script tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960180/what-is-the-point-of-using-an-id-attribute-in-a-script-tag and then add another script after it using DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.body.appendChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(<library.js file>);
document.body.appendChild(<plugins.js file>);
document.body.appendChild(<app.js file>);
</script>
```

Add the following scripts dynamically as well!

If you do not want to do this, then you'll have to fetch the DOM elements using `$('html').html()` in your script and use the technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315948/insert-html-before-element-in-javascript-without-jquery) as suggested by @Liam.

BUT! If you want to load the above mentioned scripts after loading your new library, there has to be a reason for that (those scripts depend on that library), in which case you should add those scripts dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is working , i did experiment on this and result is Positive. Try This code

```
   var mynewScript = document.createElement("script");
    mynewScript.type = "text/javascript";
    mynewScript.src = "http://mywebsite.com";

    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[2];   // [2] is the index of library.js

    var parentT = a.parentNode;

    parentT.insertBefore(mynewScript , a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and its work correctly

```
const ID = 'test-snippet';
        // abort if it already exists
        if ( document.getElementById( ID ) ) {
            return;
        }
        const scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
        const lastScriptTag = scriptTags[scriptTags.length - 1];
        // create new script element
        const js = document.createElement( 'script' );
        js.id = ID;
        js.src = 'https://some.js/';;
        js.type = 'text/javascript';
        js.async = true;
        // append it after the last script tag
        lastScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore( js, lastScriptTag );
```